# How about these capacitors values?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, charge

I have a 25V 100uF capacitor and a 50V 100uF one.  If I charge both up to 25 volts, then is the first one going to have 100uF of actual charge, and the second one only 50uF?

Comment: Capacitance is not a measure of charge. It is defined as the ratio of the charge stored to the voltage across it.

Comment: Nope. Both will have 100µF at 25V. The 25V one will just not last very long...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, now i see i need to learn a lot more about capacitors.

Comment: Please first work on how to ask questions in a better way

Comment: I fixed up the mess. Maybe OP will get a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100 uF means capacitance. It seldom changes with the applied voltage. If you charge both the capacitors to 25 V, both will have accumulated a charge.

Q = CV  = 100 uF x 25 V = 2500 micro coulombs.

Comment: For consistency you should probably write either '100u x 25' (no units) or '100 uF x 25 V' (both units).

Comment: oh yeahh... :-)

Comment: If you think capacitance "never changes with the applied voltage" you need to avoid designing with ceramic capacitors above a few nF.

Comment: @ThePhoton is correct. Super-capacitors and large electrolytics in general change value with voltage, just like solid carbon resistors do. Plus they change with age, which is why the tolerance is often -10%/+20%.

Comment: So do the small, high-value multilayer ceramics so popular on boards today.

Comment: Nobody has taught us that at school. Thanks for new knowledge ... :-D

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216367/why-does-capacitance-value-changes-with-applied-voltage . found reasons here.