How does DC bias on a ceramic capacitor change the piezoelectric effect?
I've looked at several technical notes on the piezoelectric effect exhibited by ceramic capacitors.
All mention that DC bias modifies this effect; but I can't find a source that explains how.
Does it increase or decrease the noise amplitude? And by how much?
Is the change only due to the bias causing a change in capacitance, or is there another effect at play?
Background: https://product.tdk.com/system/files/contents/faq/capacitors-0031/singing_capacitors_piezoelectric_effect.pdf

This has been answered here extensively before. As for noise - not only do they work as speakers, they work as microphones. Don’t use them in audio or analog signal paths.

@Kartman Can you please provide a link? If it has been I can't find it.

One hit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216367/why-does-capacitance-value-changes-with-applied-voltage/216369#216369

@Kartman Besides containing the words "piezoelectric effect" a few times there is not an answer to my question there.

The DC bias is causing the piezoelectric effect! Voltage converts to mechanical and vice-versa.

@Kartman I agree with Drew, the question is how DC bias affects the piezoelectric effect.  DC bias can cause a static dimensional change, but normally the concern is audio noise due to AC voltage.  So the question, I think, is asking if DC bias will make a difference in the magnitude of the AC piezoelectric effect.

If we assume the deflection is linear in regards to applied voltage and the mounting of the capacitor constrains the movement, then, yes, the DC component would change the maximum deflection that is possible. How would you quantify this? Sounds like a complex problem.

@Kartman Agreed.  Presumably one could run some experiments for a particular case, but there are lots of variables.
